# Additional CSS - crashing with javascript-html minifier?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, css

How can I load Additional CSS style manually in functions.php?

This is how I load my css files and js files:

```
function xxx_scripts() {

    // Load our CSS bundle.
    wp_enqueue_style('xxx-master-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/dist/bundle.min.css', array(), '1.0.0');

    // Load style.css.
    wp_enqueue_style('xxx-local-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0.0');

    // Load our JS bundle.
    wp_enqueue_script('cupola-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/dist/bundle.min.js', array(), '20150330');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'xxx_scripts');
```

But what about **Additional CSS** under **Appearance > Customise > Additional CSS**?

For instance, I have added the css below under **Appearance > Customise > Additional CSS**:

```
/*
You can add your own CSS here.

Click the help icon above to learn more.
*/

.row.row-banner {
background-color: #000;
}
```

But the style above is not loaded.

In my HTML header:

```
<style type="text/css" id="wp-custom-css"></style>
```

It is **not** there.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I found out that it is actually crashed with the function below that I have in functions.php:

```
// MINIFY JAVASCRIPT AND HTML FOR WORDPRESS WITHOUT A PLUGIN.
// http://setuix.com/minify-javascript-html-wordpress-without-plugin/
class WP_HTML_Compression
{
    // Settings
    protected $info_comment = true;

    // Variables
    protected $html;

    public function __construct($html)
    {
        if (!empty($html)) {
            $this->parseHTML($html);
        }
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->html;
    }

    protected function bottomComment($raw, $compressed)
    {
        $raw = strlen($raw);
        $compressed = strlen($compressed);

        $savings = ($raw-$compressed) / $raw * 100;
        $savings = round($savings, 2);

        return '<!--HTML compressed, size saved '.$savings.'%. From '.$raw.' bytes, now '.$compressed.' bytes-->';
    }

    protected function minifyHTML($html)
    {
        require_once ("vendor/phpwee-php-minifier/phpwee.php");

        $compressed = PHPWee\Minify::html($html);
        // $compressed = PHPWee\Minify::css($compressed);
        // $compressed = PHPWee\Minify::js($compressed);
        return $compressed;
    }

    public function parseHTML($html)
    {
        $this->html = $this->minifyHTML($html);

        if ($this->info_comment) {
            $this->html .= "\n" . $this->bottomComment($html, $this->html);
        }
    }
}

function wp_html_compression_finish($html) {
    return new WP_HTML_Compression($html);
}

function wp_html_compression_start() {
    ob_start('wp_html_compression_finish');
}
add_action('get_header', 'wp_html_compression_start');
```

Any ideas why and how I can fix this?

Comment: The Additional CSS in the customiser has nothing to do with functions.php. All you need is `wp_head()` in the theme header.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I have `wp_head()` in my theme header already but it shows nothing: `<style type="text/css" id="wp-custom-css"></style>`.